# Unable to connect to direct database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker

I am using mongo via Docker in a Node application.

Able to connect to mongo directly if I use the following connection String.

`mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017`

What this does is if I were to create a collection, it ends up in a database called **test**

 which I did not create. From what I searched around, this db name **test** is a default.

Seen examples where the connection String should include the database name as follows:

`mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/my_actual_db`

But trying to connect in this manner, it complains that my username/password is no longer correct.

Unable to see how that is possible since am using the root password plus it works if I

don't mention a DB in the connection String.

Could I please get some help on this.

1. My question is why the username/password no longer works. Is there an issue with my docker-compose file?

2. Else is there a way I could change the db name via mongoose?

 Looking at docs, I attempted to change it via the options as follows but it doesn't make a diff.

 The db is still called test.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo-instance-1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express-instance-1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

Connecting via mongoose in node app.

```
// process.env.DB_CONNECTION is the connection Strings above
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    name: 'my_actual_db', // doesn't make a diff, db name remains as test
  })
  .then(value => {
    console.log(value)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: Users in MongoDB are defined per-database.  Have you tried using [authSource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#urioption.authSource)?

Comment: I think that your name did not create when run docker, you can use environment `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my_actual_db` and re-try